# How to make a query in Access recognize a tempvar as a valid field (parameter)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm working to set up a macro in Access that will automatically run Append queries. The queries will add a new row to a specific table, with the data for the new row based on a date (week ending). Currently, I have it that each query prompts for end date of the data requested. I don't really want to run the macro have the prompt show up multiple times for the same date to be input.

From what I've found from other boards, I should be able to accomplish this by defining a tempvar using the SetTempVar action in a macro, with the variable pulling from an Input box that pops up. I have the result of the input box formatted as a date. The rest of the macro is set to run OpenQuery actions for each of the queries. Within the queries themselves, I replaced the spots I used for the previously prompted parameters ([Enter End Date]) with what should be a reference to the tempvar ([TempVars]![EndDate]).

Code for the Macro:

```
SetTempVar
      Name: EndDate
Expression: CDate(InputBox("Enter the end date of the week being added:","End Date","Enter Date"))

OpenQuery
Query Name: qryBizDByPersonAppend
      View: Datasheet
 Date Mode: Edit

OpenQuery
Query Name: qryBizDByTypeAppend
      View: Datasheet
 Date Mode: Edit

OpenQuery
Query Name: qryBizDByWhereAppend
      View: Datasheet
 Date Mode: Edit


Code for one of the queries:

TRANSFORM Count(tblCombined.Calendar) AS CountOfCalendar
SELECT [TempVars]![EndDate] AS [End]
FROM tblCombined
WHERE (((tblCombined.StartTime) Between #1/1/2019# And #12/31/2019#) AND ((tblCombined.Type) In ("Advisor Meeting","Advisor Training","Employee Group Presentation","Employer HR Meeting","Client Group Presentation","Client Group Webinar","Employee Group Presentation","Employee Group Webinar","Benefit Fair","Added Time")) AND ((tblCombined.Canceled) Is Null) AND ((tblCombined.DateScheduled)<=[TempVars]![EndDate]))
GROUP BY [TempVars]![EndDate]
PIVOT tblCombined.Calendar;
```

When I run the macro, I get an error saying that [TempVars]![EndDate] is not recognized as a valid field or expression once it gets to the OpenQuery actions. It was working fine previously with the individually prompted parameters.

Comment: I think CROSSTAB with dynamic criteria requires use of PARAMETERS clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the query wasn't recognizing the temp var was because it wasn't defined anywhere (in an actual field or as a "parameter"). I was able to get the temp var to work as the parameter by specifying it within each query. [Screenshot of tempvar defined in query as parameter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txWOD.png)